# Django: access from different network

Tags: django, python-3.x, server

I made a django server, which I ran by the command:

```
python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

When I try to connect to the server from the same computer using the `localhost:8000` everything works fine :)

However, when I try to connect to the server using `server_ip:8000` from another computer, I get the response: `ERR_CONNECTION_TIME_OUT`.

( The server ip is configured in `ALLOWED_HOSTS` )

Any ideas how to solve this problem or what might be causing it? :)

Comment: Have you tried changing the port?  Also the second computer is on the same LAN as the server right?

Comment: I have tried changing the port,this has not solved the problem. And the two computers aren't under the same LAN

Comment: Are you using the correct local_ip for the server on the second computer?

Comment: The server is not under the same LAN as the computer, but Im tryign to connect using the server_ip from the computer that runs the server and that works.

Comment: the server from where you are accessing your localhost does that have a proxy server ? like nginx ?

Comment: no it doesn't @Ahtisham

Answer (score 0):

After searching the web, solved using ngrok to tunnel the localhost of server.

Comment: how were you finding the ip address of your other device ( that you wanted to connect ) ?

Comment: the one that runs the server? 
I simply tunneled to localhost, so no need to find the non-local ip

Comment: for accessing your localhost site from another device. It needs to be connect to your server and then you have to use the local ip address not the public ip address.

Comment: I didn't understand your question